# Not able to write on ApplicationData folder

Tags: c#

I wrote a little Logger class that help me to create a log file with all application exception, actually I though to save this log inside the ApplicationData, so I've created a simple class:

```
public class Logger
{

    private static string _appDataPath =
    Environment.GetFolderPath(Environment.SpecialFolder.ApplicationData);

    private static string _logPath = _appDataPath + "\\MyApp\\Log";

    public static void log(string lines)
    {
        if (!File.Exists(_logPath)) 
        {
            Directory.CreateDirectory(_logPath);
        }

        using (StreamWriter file = new StreamWriter(_logPath))
        {
            file.WriteLine(lines);
            file.Close();
        };
    }
}
```

So how you can see I'm using the `Roaming` folder inside user `AppData`, when I call: `Logger.log("some exception message");` I get on this line:

```
using (StreamWriter file = new StreamWriter(_logPath))
```

this exception:

> System.UnauthorizedAccessException

Maybe I need to set some permission to the folder? Or I can't access properly to this path? Thanks.

Comment: you want file inside log folder or you want log to be the name of your file?

Comment: I need a log folder inside MyApp folder

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your `_logPath` variable points to the directory you want so you should be checking for its existence using `Directory.Exists` instead of `File.Exists`.

Also, you need to specify the path upto the file that you want to create and not just upto the directory. So, in my sample code, I've declared variable `_logFileName` which specifies the name of log file to be created.

This is what your class needs to look like:

```
public class Logger
{
    private static string _appDataPath =
    Environment.GetFolderPath(Environment.SpecialFolder.ApplicationData);

    private static string _logPath = _appDataPath + "\\MyApp\\Log";
    private static string _logFileName = "logfile.txt";

    public static void log(string lines)
    {
        if (!Directory.Exists(_logPath))
        {
            Directory.CreateDirectory(_logPath);
        }

        using (StreamWriter file = new StreamWriter(Path.Combine(_logPath, _logFileName)))
        {
            file.WriteLine(lines);
            file.Close();
        };
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Your code creates a **folder** named

%APPDATA%\MyApp\Log

Of course, being this a folder and not a file, the StreamWriter cannot write to a folder

Change your code to add a filename to the folder

```
if (!Directory.Exists(_logPath)) 
{
    Directory.CreateDirectory(_logPath);
}
string logFile = Path.Combine(_logPath, "myApp.Log");
using (StreamWriter file = new StreamWriter(logFile, true))
{
    file.WriteLine(lines);
    file.Close();
};
```